# Clickable desktop notifications for chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I like the **desktop** notification functionality, but it is rather inconvenient to have the notification popping up on my screen and not being able to click it (to go to the chat).

Can we have GMail-like notifications for chat, in which the chat window will focus upon clicking it?

[image: thanks to sathya for pinging me]

Comment: I dont understand the request....

Comment: You mean the HTML5 notifications? I wasn't aware they supported custom click actions, I figured the browser decided what to do when you click on it

Comment: @Neal look at my question. I think you'll get what he means

Comment: @Neal I have updated the question

Comment: @bckbck -- ok now i get it ^_^

Answer (score 3):

It would be fine.

He's talking about "Desktop notification in chat", which popups small windows (like ICQ) when someone @mentions you.

But when this notification popups, you have to manually go to browser & search between tabs to find your chat room, which is pretty hard in mess like

[image]

mine. So I'm with your idea

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just...not do that? Why would you have 100 tabs open in a single window?

Comment: @Michael: As someone mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98703) "That is an issue to some regardless of how you, specifically, navigate Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the notification will now open/show/focus the chat window that generated the notification. Note that if you have multiple tabs/windows open with chat rooms, the choice of *which* tab to focus may seem rather arbitrary (it will generally be the one that has been open the longest).

Answer (score 2):

This would be nice feature and improve desktop workflow for those of us that leave chat open somewhere almost all the time.

It might also be useful to cause the chat app to switch to the room that generated the ping when the room was focused using the desktop notification. Additionally, the same highlight/focus action that happens when following a backref should be triggered so that you go straight to the message that initiated the ping.