# Edit search feature "url" to be able to search in all stackexchange question-links formats

Tags: feature-request, search

I know that title is little bit strange, but I didn't find correct clarification in one sentence.

Recently, `url:""` special search feature was announced.

I'd like if we could search for all questions/answers contains url to my question/answer.

**Proposal 1:**

Add something like "View all urls linking to your question/answer". It was proposed before but never realized/denied. It would show list like

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12121/search-features-list
http://google.com/?q=add+useful+search+feature+to+stacckoverflow
```

**Proposal 2:**

Add search feature to existing url searching. When I search for

> url:"[Is it necessary to change the title of the page when asking a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98703/is-it-necessary-to-change-the-title-of-the-page-when-asking-a-new-question)"

there are no results,because question-links formats are (maybe this question I'm writing will appear (?))

```
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98703/is-it-necessary-to-change-the-title-of-the-page-when-asking-a-new-question
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98703
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98703/is-it-necessary-to-change-the-title-of-the-page-when-asking-a-new-question/#98703
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98703/is-it-necessary-to-change-the-title-of-the-page-when-asking-a-new-question
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98703/
```

etc... I know I can add wildchar (`*`) but it is complicated and slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reluctant to add this because the feature already exists in the site itself.  On the sidebar we have a **Linked** section that shows everything that the question, answers and comments link to, and *questions that link to this one* (it shows both directions).

So for your example question, simply go there, and you see this:

[image: Linked section]

Look at that second item, seem familiar? :) That's *this* question, since the URL appears in it.

Comment: I'm probably blind, but what does have "clickable desktop ......" have to do with "Is it necessary...."? (I do not see any relationship (link(s)) between them)

Comment: @genesis-φ - They're linked because of your comment on the "clickable desktop" question that links back, on this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99285/clickable-desktop-notifications-for-chat/99286#99286

Comment: I do not see it on main site: (http://phpcode.eu/images/1313931203.png)

Comment: @genesis-φ - It will only appear if there are linked questions.